# Creating a Silverlight library with dependecies composed via MEF

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, mef

I have a Silverlight 4 *library* `L` which has a dependency that is to be provided at run-time via a plugin `P`.

I am using a `DeploymentCatalog` along the lines of the example provided by [MEF documentation](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DeploymentCatalog&referringTitle=Guide) and all is well: the XAP of the plugin `P` is correctly downloaded asynchronously and the import is satisfied.

However, I cannot control the details on the Silverlight application `A` that will be using library `L` and I cannot exclude that `A` itself might want to use MEF: therefore it's possible that at some point `A` might issue a <strike>`CompositionHost.SatisfyImports(...)`</strike> `CompositionHost.Initialize(catalog)` call for its own purposes which I understand can only be invoked once.

Am I missing something here or partitioning the application across multiple XAPs can only be achieved if one has complete control of the Silverlight application and libraries?

Stefano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CompositionHost.SatisfyImports can be called many times.  [CompositionHost.Initialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382834%28VS.95%29.aspx) can only be called once.  As a library, it is not a good idea to call that method because the application may do so.  Since you need to create and use a DeploymentCatalog, it's probably better if you don't use CompositionHost at all in your library, since you want to avoid calling the Initialize method, which would be the way to hook the CompositionHost to the DeploymentCatalog.

You can create your own CompositionContainer hooked up to the DeploymentCatalog and call GetExports or SatisfyImports on the container you created.  CompositionHost is pretty much just a wrapper around a static CompositionContainer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not usually a good idea to tie yourself to a single dependency injection container in a library, instead you'd usually want to abstract that away using something like the [CommonServiceLocator](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/), which leaves the choice of IoC container a preference of whoever is consuming your library.

Comment: I was not aware of the CommonServiceLocator library. I will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I only started with MEF in Silverlight a month ago, so I'm definitely not an authority.

The first thing I noticed is that  CompositionHost.SatisfyImports has been replaced with [CompositionInitializer.SatisfyImports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382873%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)   .
    Second I could not find any reference to "SatisfyImports can only be invoked once"
    My scenario is the following:

- I have a BL xap which I use/link to from my application
- The BL has some Imports that will be satisfied by calling SatisfyImports from the Application
- The BL also has some imports that
  cannot/will not be resolved until a
  certain custom (third party)
  module/xap will be loaded (loaded
  when demand that is). When the custom
  module becomes available (is loaded)
  I solve the missing imports with an
  extra call to
  CompositionInitializer.SatisfyImports:

E.g:

```
  If DomainSpecificModuleLogic Is Nothing Then  
     'this is required to trigger recomposition and resolve imports to the ThirdPartyModule
     System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionInitializer.SatisfyImports(Me)  
  End If
```

So I have multiple calls to SatisfyImports (at different moments in time) and no problems due to this -> you do not required control over the whole application, just make sure that when someone accesses an object from your library that uses MEF, you have a call to SatisfyImports
**Note:** my BL is a singleton, so for sure I am calling SatisfyImports on the same object multiple times.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I put the wrong function name in my original question. The function that can only be issued once is CompositionHost.Initialize(catalog).